# dblog not working, page shows a 500 Internal server error

Tags: log-messages

My problem starts in a contact form with an upload box, it does everything right and sends the email, except that, on upload it shows:

> Warning: strtr() [function.strtr]: The second argument is not an array in syslog_watchdog() (line 105 of syslog/syslog.module)

So I found [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1396368) post to resolve my problem above, but it just showed me another problem, a problem with dblog, the page shows me a 500 error, I can't access it.

I couldn't find any help to solve this matter so if anyone knows some way to figure out what is causing this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome Nuno. Please elaborate in what you changed code-wise or what changes you did more specifically, instead of posting an article that people need to read in addition to your question.

Comment: Hello, i used a theme named Surreal, in terms of code i didn't change nothing but CSS, so i can't elaborate unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the incorrect watchdog data was saved to the database. Truncate the 'watchdog' table that contains your dblog messages in your database and you should be good.